# Navigation back from the Search Center in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, enterprise-search

We have a dilemma with our implementation of Search Center. I am sure I am not alone with this. Basically, in some site 3 levels deep on one web app the search redirects them to the search center at a different web app. The user finds what they want then wants to go back to the site they started at. But they can't there isn't a breadcrumb back to the originating site.

What have others done to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are "loosing" your navigation is due to the master page being used by default in SharePoint search center (in 2010) - the minimal.master.

Practically, you would have several options to fix this as describe already on the web, but 2 most used:

1. On the Search Center, apply your current master page, which would
   require you to re-create the Search Pages (both the search box and
   search results), using a compatible layout, by placing required web
   parts.
2. Update the actual page layout of the search page to become compatibile with the v4.master, as many explain (e.g. Randy Drisgill http://blog.drisgill.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-standard-search-center-branding.html) - customizing either the Page Layout (Enterprise search center) or the web part page (for the Simple Search Center)

Comment: I mentioned the Search Center is on a different web app. But even if it wasn't the master page wouldn't change anything.  When you execute the search you get transferred to a new site.  Getting back to your original location is our issue.

Comment: Yes, got that, i'm simply explaining your options. the simplest being to change the minimal.master to include a LinkButton to ~site, or manually insert the navigational controls, because by default, none are present.